# Getting HTML with Pycurl

Tags: python, pycurl

I've been trying to retrieve a page of HTML using pycurl, so I can then parse it for relevant information using str.split and some for loops. I know Pycurl retrieves the HTML, since it prints it to the terminal, however, if I try to do something like

```
html = str(c.perform())
```

The variable will just hold a string which says "None".

How can I use pycurl to get the html, or redirect whatever it sends to the console so it can be used as a string as described above?

Thanks a lot to anyone who has any suggestions!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

this will send a request and store/print the response body:

```
from StringIO import StringIO    
import pycurl

url = 'http://www.google.com/'

storage = StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, url)
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, storage.write)
c.perform()
c.close()
content = storage.getvalue()
print content
```

if you want to store the response headers, use:

```
c.setopt(c.HEADERFUNCTION, storage.write)
```

Comment: Great! That does exactly what I've been looking for. Though, one line is incorrect. It should say storage = StringIO.StringIO(). Otherwise, an error is raised. Regardless, thanks for your help!!

Comment: i think it is correct as-is.  notice I do 'from StrongIO import StringIO'

Comment: Ah, that might be it. I checked my source and just imported the entire library. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Any chance you might update this for Python3?  Looks like Python3 deprecated StringIO in favor of io.StringIO, which doesn't quite work as above.

Comment: For Python 3 use `io.BytesIO` instead, but then `.getvalue()` will return `bytes`, so you should turn them into string with `.decode("utf-8")`

Answer (score 6):

The perform() method executes the html fetch and writes the result to a function you specify.  You need to provide a buffer to put the html into and a write function.  Usually, this can be accomplished using a StringIO object as follows:

```
import pycurl
import StringIO

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://www.google.com/")

b = StringIO.StringIO()
c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)
c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.MAXREDIRS, 5)
c.perform()
html = b.getvalue()
```

You could also use a file or tempfile or anything else that can store data.